# System.Assert is showing null

Tags: apex, soql

Hi friends i got a requirement to update a currency field on case for a specific record type with some criteria.Everything is working fine. when i create a cases directly.But my test class are fail because they are getting null instead of value in system.assert statements.

My Apex code:

```
public static void RevenueLoss(List<Case> CaseTriggers) 
    {
        Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Order'].Id;
        List<Case> CaseIDs = new List<Case>();
        system.debug('Old Values'+CaseTriggers);
        for (Case s : CaseTriggers)
        {
            if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && s.Case_Details__c =='Cancell') 
            {
                // Loop through and add caseId's to the list.
                CaseIDs.add(s);
            }
        }
        set<Id> CaseAccountIds = new set<Id>();
        Integer DaysDifference;
        List<Account> Accountstoupdate =new List<Account>();
        List<Zuora__Subscription__c> Subscription=new List<Zuora__Subscription__c>();
        for(Case c : caseTriggers)
        {
            // Loop through and add AccountId's to the list.
            CaseAccountIds.add(c.AccountId);
            system.debug('***TTT****'+CaseAccountIds);
        }
        Subscription=[SELECT Id,Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c FROM Zuora__Subscription__c WHERE Zuora__Account__c = :CaseAccountIds ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
        for(Zuora__Subscription__c sub:Subscription) 
        {
            for(Case cs:CaseIDs) 
            {
                DaysDifference=cs.Revenue_effective__c.daysBetween(sub.Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c);
                cs.Revenue_Loss__c=cs.Total_units_ordered__c *DaysDifference *cs.ARPU__c;
            }
        }

    }
```

My Test class:

```
static testmethod void TestRevenueLoss() 
    {
        System.runAs(su)
        {
            Account a =new Account(Name='Internal TestRevenueLoss');
            insert a;
            Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Order'].Id;
            List<Case> CaseList =new List<Case>();
            Zuora__Subscription__c z= new Zuora__Subscription__c(Zuora__Account__c=a.ID,
                                                                 Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c=date.Today(),
                                                                 Zuora__Zuora_Id__c='123');
            for(Integer i=0;i<=100;i++) 
            {
                case c=new case(AccountId =a.ID,Case_Details__c='Cancell',Churn_under_180_days__c='No',
                                RecordTypeId=recordTypeId,
                                Azuga_Invoice_no__c='123'+i,X3G_GSM_OBD2_CANADA__c=-2,Contract_Term__c=24,
                                Subscription_Rate__c=19.00,Trial_units_billed_in_this_order__c='No',
                                Revenue_effective__c=Date.today());
                CaseList.add(c);
            }
            test.startTest();
            // Insert the case records that cause the trigger to execute.
            insert CaseList;
            // Stop the test, this changes limit context back to test from trigger.
            test.stopTest();
            List<Case> insertedcases = [SELECT Id,Revenue_Loss__c FROM Case WHERE Id IN :CaseList];
            // Assert that the Description fields contains the proper value now.
            for(Case l :insertedcases)
            {
                System.assertEquals(0,l.Revenue_Loss__c);
            }
        } 
    }
```

Revenue_Loss__c is acurrency field.

Comment: I think you want `System.assertNotEquals(0,l.Revenue_Loss__c);`

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below statement in your trigger method -

```
cs.Revenue_Loss__c=cs.Total_units_ordered__c *DaysDifference *cs.ARPU__c;
```

Since "Revenue_Loss__c" is a currency field please initialize both **Total_units_ordered__c** and **ARPU__c** in your test method so that they are not nulls and it should work !!!